Reference for a normal CDF/PDF inequality
I am looking for references or any paper/book/report where the following inequality involving the standard Gaussian CDF and PDF appears or was used:
$$
     \Phi(x)\big(1-\Phi(x)\big) > \phi^2(x), \forall{x}\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
I found the inequality here: Normal pdf/cdf inequality, and a proof is given as well.  But no other information is provided.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
